# How I can internationalize variables within the function _e () __ ()?

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

I wish internationalize a dynamic variable.

I have the following code:

```
_e($widget['description'], MyStaticClass::$i18n_prefix);
```

When I run the poedit this internationalization (`$widget['description']`) is not done.

How I can I make it dynamic?

Thanks

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113777, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `_e()` and `__()` are wrappers for PHP's native [`gettext()` function](http://php.net/_) or similar (please correct me if I'm wrong). When you scan the files for importing into a .po or .pot file, the variables are not interpreted by PHP and so you need to do it in the declaration of the variable instead. Like this:

```
$widget['description'] = _e("your text here", MyStaticClass::$i18n_prefix);
```

And then you can use `$widget['description']` however you want. If you want to then include that as part of another string, you can use `sprintf`:

```
$var = sprintf(
    _e("Write %s please", MyStaticClass::$i18n_prefix),
    $widget['description']
);
```

And when you echo `$var` it should produce `Write your text here please`. The translators will then see two strings to be translated, `your text here` and `Write %s please`. You should probably also include a comment using the defined prefix to let the translator know what the `%s` part means if it is not clear. Note that the comment must be on the preceeding line above the `_e()` function.